# Custom border for UIView using CALayer and autolayout

Tags: uiview, calayer, autolayout

I have to draw a custom border for a UIView.

I already have code to do that but it was written before we started using autolayout.

The code basically adds a sublayer of width/height=1.0f

```
-(void)BordeIzquierdo:(UIColor *)pcColor cfloatTamanio:(CGFloat )pcfloatTamanio
{
    CALayer* clElemento = [self layer];
    CALayer *clDerecho = [CALayer layer];
    clDerecho.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    clDerecho.borderWidth = pcfloatTamanio;
    clDerecho.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, pcfloatTamanio, self.frame.size.height);
    [clDerecho setBorderColor:pcColor.CGColor];
    [clElemento addSublayer:clDerecho];
}
```

Now the problem is that with autolayout, this happens before layoutSubViews. So `UIView.layer.frame` is (0,0;0,0) and so the sublayer added is not shown because it has width/height=0.0f

Now how can I make this code without transferring this custom drawing to another method executed after `viewDidLoad` such as `didLayoutSubviews`.

I would like this styling to be correctly applied before `viewDidLoad` is called.

- Is there anything like autolayout constraints that I can use with `CALayers`?
- Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no CALayer autoresizing or constraints in iOS. (There is on Mac OS X, but no in iOS.)

Your requirements here are unreasonable. You say that you refuse to move the call to `BordeIzquierdo:`. But you *can't* give `clDerecho` a correct size until you know the size of `self` (and therefore `self.layer`). Half the art of Cocoa touch programming is putting your code in the right place. You *must* find the right place to put the call to `BordeIzquierdo:` so that the values you need have meaning at the moment it is called.

What I would do is put it in `layoutSubviews` along with a BOOL flag so that you only do it once.

Comment: I would say that setting the appearance of a view before is laid out is a reasonable requirement :) The fact that it is currently not possible doesn't make it unreasonable just practically unattainable. What I wanted was to have all the code that sets the appearance in a single place, if no other option exists, I would have to have code in two places `viewDidLoad`and `layoutSubvies`.

Comment: Well, hold on. This is a UIView subclass, so there is no `viewDidLoad`. But there is a `layoutSubviews`. So that is just one place.

Comment: Also, yes, I'm sorry but I would insist that fighting the framework is unreasonable. You use the framework by letting the framework use you.

Comment: I tried adding the code in layoutSubviews with a `BOOL` flag as you proposed but the first time it is called the frame is (0,0;0,0) so the new layer is not created correctly and the flag is set, so the second time nothing happens. For the moment I will leave the code without validating the flag, that works. I just hope it doesn't bite me later with performance.

Comment: Sorry about the CGRectZero the first time. However, you can still use a flag; as soon as it isn't CGRectZero and you *can* create the layer, set the flag. Otherwise you might end up adding 1000 layers!

Comment: Not sure what was I doing wrong but putting the code in `layoutSubviews` worked just fine. Thank you!!!